# Query con Left Join Count con resultado erróneo

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, join, count

Tengo dos tablas en mi BD.
La primera es una lista de dependencias:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La segunda es una que relaciona el id de un documento con el iddependencia de una dependencia, por tanto, indica que una dependencia tiene un documento asignado.

Estoy creando un mantenimiento donde quiero incluir el número de documentos que tiene una dependencia asignados.

Para ello utilizo el siguiente query:

```
SELECT d.id, d.descripcion, d.estructura, COUNT(u.iddependencia) AS Documentos
FROM dependencias d 
LEFT JOIN dep_x_doc u 
ON d.id = u.iddependencia
WHERE d.estructura = '1' and d.estado = 'A'
GROUP BY u.iddependencia
ORDER BY d.id ASC;
```

En teoría el resultado me trae todas las dependencias con el número de documentos asignados, incluidas las que tiene cero documentos asignados. Acá está:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero, el detalle está en que la dependencia con el ID 131, y 132 no tienen documentos asignados, y en teoría el query anterior debería incluirlos en el resultado, como lo hace con el ID 130.

Si uso el mismo query y condiciono a que me traiga el ID 131, si trae el resultado correcto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es, porque en el Query no incluye todas las dependencias que tiene cero documentos asignados, solamente el primer registro que encuentra al ejecutar la consulta lo muestra en el resultado.

Comment: ¿que ocurre si cambias esto: `GROUP BY u.iddependencia` por esto `GROUP BY d.id` en tu consulta?

Comment: En efecto, me solucionó el problema! Ese era el detalle.  Podría explicarme el porque para entenderlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que el problema es como estás agrupando.

Cambia el
GROUP BY u.iddependencia

Por
GROUP BY d.id

¿porqué?

Estás haciendo un LEFT JOIN de la tabla d con la tabla u. Eso quiere decir que puede haber columnas de la tabla u con valores nulos. En tu ejemplo sería la columna u.iddependencia.
Agrupar el resultado con columna u.iddependencia sería agrupar con columna que pueda tener valores nulos, no creo que sea buena idea.
Si agrupas por (d.id) ese campo en teoría nunca es nulo y por ende no se brinca ningún renglón.

Comment: En efecto, ese era el problema!  Hice el cambio y me funcionó perfecto.  Podría explicarme el porque?  Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Hola. Estas haciendo un LEFT JOIN, o sea que el resultado va ser los registros de una tabla con registros de otra de los cuales algunos pueden ser nulos. No creo sea buena idea agrupar registros que pueden estar nulos, mejor usar los registros que son consistentes, que serían los de la tabla que vas a unir, o sea dependencias.

Comment: mejor edité respuesta para agregar comentarios. saludos.

Comment: Me queda claro.  Funcionó muy bien!  Muchas gracias.